# import tab separated csv file with partial data into mysql table with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL table which has about 30 columns.
I have a CSV file which has about 10 columns.

I want to use phpMyAdmin to update the data from the CSV file in the database without changing the rest of the data.

For example, the MySQL would be:

```
id, code,  name,     description, a,   b,   c,   x,  y,   z
10, rbmls, Joe Blow, Neighbor,    100, 200, 500, 80, 800, 10
```

The CSV could contain:

```
id[TAB]code [TAB]a [TAB]b  [TAB]c
10[TAB]rbmls[TAB]10[TAB]300[TAB]0
```

I want to match the data in the CSV and the MySQL table by ID and then overwrite the data from the CSV in the MySQL table without deleting anything else.

The desired result of the above example would be:

```
id, code, name, description, a, b, c, x, y, z
10, rbmls, Joe Blow, Neighbor, 10, 300, 0, 80, 800, 10
```

How do I do that in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` has a column-specification at the end. [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ... 
INTO TABLE ... 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, code, a, b, c)
```

From MySQL-Doc:

> By default, when no column list is provided at the end of the LOAD DATA INFILE statement, input lines are expected to contain a field for each table column. If you want to load only some of a table's columns, specify a column list: 
>   LOAD DATA INFILE 'persondata.txt' INTO TABLE persondata (col1,col2,...);

**Alternative**

Load the data in a temporary table and do an `INSERT ... UPDATE` from there to the main-table. Something like that:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ... INTO TABLE `temp` ...

INSERT INTO mainTable (id, code, a, b, c)
SELECT * FROM `temp`
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE code=VALUES(code), a=VALUES(a), b=VALUES(b), c=VALUES(c);
```

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: I tried your first solution but it seems I am doing something wrong. I get #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LINE (id, code, a, b, c) at line 4.

Comment: It's `LINES` not `LINE`, sorry. I Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, the syntax seems to be correct now but I get a different error: "#1045 - Access denied." It seems strange as I am already logged in to phpMyAdmin and I only get this message when trying to execute the statement. I use a hosted solution, so I have no full access to the config file. However, I have a panel to check and change my privileges and per what I can see the user has all the rights to do what I am trying to do. Any ideas?

Comment: The access to the desired file you try to load might be denied

Comment: that seems to be it. Where do I need to put the file? Maybe I just have it in the wrong location.

Comment: I gave up and wrote a php script that handles it for me. I can't believe there is no simple way to do this in phpMyAdmin.